# How to know when to scale your FastAPI app?

Tags: fastapi

I'm currently following the process of https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/ to get a Docker FastAPI container up and running, and it works like a charm.

We're currently on the nginx+uwsgi+flask stack and we want to get onboard with FastAPI.

The big question we have is:

What metric do we use to tell us we need to scale up or out?

In our current stack, uwsgi exposes the "Max Workers" and "Idle Workers" metrics, so it's super easy to answer that question.  If the number of Idle Workers metrics starts creeping down to zero, we either scale UP (increase the number of workers), or scale OUT (spin up more uwsgi containers behind our load balancer).  Easy peasy!

With FastAPI, how do we know ahead of time when we need to scale?
Does FastAPI have any metrics we can query? Or is the answer, "scale up when your cpu/memory is maxing out?"

thanks,

A FastAPI Newbie

Comment: That would depend on what asgi server and process manager you're using; `uvicorn` or `gunicorn` usually. gunicorn can export to statsd as a means of instrumentation, but not sure if it will give you the required information about idle workers (i.e. what the workers parameter includes): https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/instrumentation.html

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks for the reply!  Any process manager that can give me metrics is the answer :). I looked into instrumentation, but it only shows code instrumentation (ie how fast did X function run), not about idle workers.  I would like to know "how many servers do I need to process X requests? 1 server, 1K servers? or something in between?)